# Is it possible to edit posts in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know that now it is possible to edit comments.

Is there a way to do the same with old posts?

Comment: lucaghera, please keep comments civilized and be nice, I have deleted your previous comment.

Comment: I would suggest marking Alex's post as the answer to give it maximum visibility. Most people don't seem to realize you can edit posts if you attach a photo. I keep a 32x32 blank jpeg for just this purpose. Every "text only" post I make I attach this little icon to it and then I can edit all my posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now possible to edit the Facebook posts, also the old ones.
Just click on the arrow on the up-left corner of the post and select `Edit...`.

[This website](http://www.complex.com/tech/2013/09/facebook-status-update-edits) provides more information.

Answer (score 12):

**Update 9/27/13**.

**Yes.**

It is now possible to edit your facebook posts. There is a down arrow at the top right of each post made by you that has the text "Edit..." where you can change the text of your posts.

Comment: you can edit Note posts, see my solution below.

Comment: Editing your status updates is now possible.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 26/09/2013:** This is now possible for the Android users, the iOS and web ones following soon.

[Source](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/26/edit-facebook-post/).

---

Short answer, yes.
Long answer, yes, but there is a caveat: you can only edit the text of statuses that have photos attached. So, if you posted a status update accompanied by a photo, you can edit the text of the status. (And I don’t know how far back you can go.)

To do it, follow the steps below.

1. Click on the date of the post.
   [image]
2. Click on **Edit**
   [image]
3. Edit the text of the post
   [image]
4. When you are done, click **Done Editing**
   [image]
5. Voilà!
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

As of recently, you actually can edit status updates. It's a relatively new feature (according to *The Huffington Post* it began rolling out on 6/22/12). If you navigate to your timeline (assuming you've switched to timeline already), you'll see a button with a pencil appear when you hover your mouse over a post. If you take longer than 30 seconds to choose to make an edit, a little *Edited* badge will appear below the post, and clicking on it will allow people to see the edit history.

**Sources**

- [Huffington Post article about the feaure](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/06/22/facebook-edit-feature_n_1619710.html)

EDIT: Note that this only works for status updates, not posts to someone else's timeline/wall.

Comment: This button only allows me to change the data and add a location but not to change the text of the post.

Comment: Er, I guess the feature doesn't do what I expected it to. I'm sorry. You can edit _comments_, but it seems editing status updates isn't a feature yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, if you use Facebook Notes : http://facebook.com/notes
though facebook dont heavily promote the use of FB Notes any more, you can still use them, to create one go to the URL above, and click the "write a new note" button. When you create a note you can use basic HTML tags, including IMG tags, and you can edit notes after you have published them, so you can change the IMG tags and the text in the notes. I believe the first img tag you insert into the note is the one that will be used in the preview that gets displayed in the newsfeed.

If however you are talking about plain status updates/posts, the answer is no.

There is one case where you can edit the textual contents of a post, and thats if you make a photo post. As the text content that gets posted with the image, is the image’s description and images descriptions are still editable even after you posted them, which means you can still edit those types of posts (though obviously you can’t replace the image).

Answer (score 1):

Much like wax eagle says there is no way to do this BUT there is a nice workaround that basically does the same thing as deleting it, other than the fact that you will still be able to see it.

What you want to do is go to the post and change the privacy options of the post and make it only viewable to "me" (see image below). This means only you can see the post, and no one else can!

[image: Facebook - Private post]

Answer (score -1):

The way I work around this inability to directly edit a post problem, is simply by cutting and pasting:

- Step 1: select the entire post you want to edit and then cut or copy 
  the entire posting
- Step 2: go to a new What's on your mind -click and paste what you
  cut or copied
- Step 3: make your edits and then hit post -voila -you have a
  corrected post
- Step 4: go back to original post asnd delete it as that post has now
  been replaced by newly edited post

Comment: That's fine, assuming there aren't any comments on the original.

Comment: As Jacob points out in his edit , this is a simple matter of cutting and pasting; I outlined the specific steps for those of you out there who do not normally use this process. And, as noted, you will lose any comments, likes, etc. But at least you will have a corrected post.